# Optimal point placement on integer lattice

Tags: ds.algorithms, optimization, ds.data-structures, computational-geometry, voronoi

What is known about the following point placement problem?
For positive integers $N$, $n<N^2$, and $N\times N$ grid $\mathcal{G}$, compute
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu_1(N,n)\triangleq\min_{\mathcal{P}\subset \mathcal{G},\,|\mathcal{P}|=n}\sum_{g\in \mathcal{G} }d_1(g,\mathcal{P})
\end{eqnarray*}
where $d_1$ denotes Manhattan distance ($l_1$ distance).

1. Any known reasonably efficient algorithms to compute $\mu_1(N,n)$?
2. What (symmetry) properties one should expect from an optimal $\mathcal{P}$ or its convex
   hull?
3. Is anything known about continuous versions of this problem? For instance, the grid $\mathcal{G}$ is replaced by a unit square $\mathcal{S}$, and $\mathcal{P}$ is measurable subset of $\mathcal{S}$ or area $\sigma<1$ - and of course a different definition of $\mu_1$

It looks related to computing some type of 'optimal' $l_1$-DVD (Discrete Voronoi Diagram) for $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Complexity theory will not help you with this problem: Since the underlying language is sparse, Mahaney's theorem makes it unlikely that you should be able to establish NP-hardness.

Comment: Thanks, @Gamow. I modified the question.

Comment: So, choose $n$ "centers" in the $N\times N$ grid so as to minimize the sum, over all points in the grid, of the distance from the point to its nearest center?  This seems like a special case of the metric $k$-medians problem, for which there are poly-time algorithms that compute solutions with value at most a constant times the optimal.  Most of those algorithms are LP-based.  You might study the integrality gap (if any) of the underlying LP in this particular case, and/or use an LP (or ILP) solver to solve moderate-sized instances.

Comment: You could also adapt the standard local-improvement algorithms for _centroidal power diagrams_ to this problem, although those algorithms work better for minimizing the sum of the squared Euclidean distances.